# the countdown timer inside while loop not working

Tags: unity, c#, timer

i am instantiating prefab cars ... the clones had a random countdown timer with each one off them and its working very well but the its not  decreasing its not counting down the timer is inside the spawn method the spawn method is inside the WHILE loop and the while loop is inside the UpDate() ... i  tried  to move the countdown to Update() but didnn't worked ... any ideas ...Thank You!

```
void Update()
{
    p -= Time.deltaTime; 

        while (carNumber < cars && p <= 0 )
        { 
            SpawnCars();
            print(carNumber);
            p = 5;               
    }

}
```

and this is the spawn method:

```
 public void SpawnCars()
{
    if (spawnAllowed)
    {
        // choose a random strat point 1/6     
        randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
        // choose a random car 1/6
        randomSpawnCars = Random.Range(0, Cars.Length);
        // clone randomly a car(1/6) from a random pre_set-points(1/6)
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(Cars[randomSpawnCars], spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 180, 0)) as GameObject;
        // carNumber will count how many cloned car 
        carNumber++;
        // destroy the  cloned car after N sec
       // Destroy(obj, 8);
        // every cloned car will take a tag with it
        obj.gameObject.tag = "select" + k;
        k++;
        rcf = obj.GetComponent<RayCastForward>();
        //textCDT
        time = Random.Range(4f, time);
        TextMesh txt = FindObjectOfType<TextMesh>();


//the Timer:
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        coolDown = time.ToString("0");
        txt.text = ""+coolDown;

    }
}
```

edit: i forgot to tell that the timer  is inside SpawnCars().

Comment: this while loop will loop at most once, since you set `p = 5` and have the condition `p <= 0`. Shouldn't you initialize with `p = 5;` and inside the loop do `p -= Time.deltaTime; ` and change the condition to `p >= 0`?

Comment: `p`is a spawn timer ... 1 car every 5 sec ... and `cars`is how many car will be instantiated ... and this loop is looping correctly ..if i put 'cars = 4' it will give 4 cars (a car every 5sec)

Comment: Then it looks more like it should be an `if`, because after setting `p = 5` the loop will terminate after first loop because of the condition `p <= 0`.

Comment: The countdown only runs once each time you spawn a car, you need to put it in 'update' somewhere.

Comment: Additionally, your `time` variable inside `Cars` isn't a timer. `p` is your timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! After 3 days, I found the solution:

1. I created a new script
2. attached it to the 3d Text
3. Add code to change the text:

   ```
   time-= Time.deltatime; // CountingDown
   GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = time.ToString("0"); // Show the countdown in the 3d text
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). You can run `SpawnCars();` there and use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);` to make it run every 5 seconds. You have to put `StartCoroutine("YourCoroutine");` in `Start();` and when you don't need anymore cars you will have to call `StopCoroutine("YourCoroutine");`.